# I want to texture all the cubes I've created in Geometry nodes

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, image

[image]I'm giving material to the cubes I've created in Geometry nodes, but I'm not able to propagate a single image piece by piece to larger cubes. I hope you understand what I'm saying. Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

I want to do this
[image]

But what I can do is pixel by pixel.
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the image directly inside Geometry Nodes as a color attribute stored on a domain of your choice:

[image]

Only thing you need to make sure is that the size and ratio of your grid matches the ratio and size of your image's. You can accomplish that with the help of the `Image Info` node (this is a new-ish one, so I'm not sure for which versions of Blender it's available—I'm on 3.5). By default the image values will be inside a unit square, between $(0,0)$ and $(1,1)$. You can resize one axis according to the image's real ratio so it's not stretched or squeezed. In my setup I'm keeping the *Y* axis at $1$, and scaling the *X* axis by the ratio. I'm using the same values to size my grid so they match:

[image]

I'm storing this color information on the *Face* domain here so the cubes act more like pixels, but you could use the *Point* domain for more gradual shifts, etc. I'm also using a `Wave` texture distortion and capturing the Z value of the cubes so I can color them differently as an example, you can adapt that to your specific requirements. You use these stored attributes in you shader node tree with the help of the `Attribute` node:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your help. I am also using blender 3.5 version. I tried to apply the nodes you made to my own project, but I couldn't. Your nodes and mine are very different. I wonder if I upload my blend file, can you make changes on it? This is exactly what I want. The side surface of the cube will have intermittent blue lights, the top surface of the cubes will display a single image. But when I add an image in the texture section, I only see the repetition of the image on a single cube.

Comment: @buse If you upload your file to blend-exchange.com I'll try to have a look at it, though I'm a bit busy atm so I'm not sure how fast I can get back to you.

Comment: The file size is quite high. So I sent it via wetranfer. here is the link.
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0aec9d3e772660280ee7709781e187e520221228134035/246d304ca8851458d0f4fee6249995b520221228134053/fecca2?trk=TRN_TDL_01&utm_campaign=TRN_TDL_01&utm_medium=email&utm_source=sendgrid

Comment: help me please. Since I can't describe this problem, I can't find a solution anywhere else. Any tutorial can be of great help to me.

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite ill and a bit bed-ridden at the moment so I can't look at it immediately, I'll have a look once I get up if you're still in need of help by then.

Comment: I hope you get well soon. I actually sort of solved the problem. I can spread the image to all cubes, but there is only one color in one cube. That's why the image looks weird. It actually looks like the prefix you made. But what I want to do is something different. Thank you for your help.